# Android Studio Location API implementing class signature

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Guys how Do I change the class signature to implement googleapiclient? If you click on image it shows the tutorial but doesn't show clearly what to do. I don't understand when it says implement it because I don't know how? Can anyone help?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    //private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private TextView locationText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    private void updateDisplay(){
        if (currentLocation==null){
            locationText.setText("determining your location...");
        } else {
            locationText.setText(
                    String.format("Your location:\n%2f, %.2f", currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                            currentLocation.getLongitude()));

        }
    }

    private LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
            currentLocation=location;
            updateDisplay();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        updateDisplay();
        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        //locationManager.removeUpdates(mListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> how Do I change the class signature to implement googleapiclient?

Add `implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` to your class, and implement the methods that [it requires](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html).

Comment: I am trying this myself too and when typing "implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks" the GoogleApiClient comes red and it does not give me a option to implement it (pressing alt and enter)

Comment: @user3622142: Then apparently you have not [set up the Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) for this project.